# Retrieving data from firebase returns null in a particular adapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass some data from my adapter to another activity, but it shows some of the data as null, I couldn't figure out the reason especially since this error only appears in this particular adapter, I have other adapters that are working perfectly with no null values.
Here is how I'm trying to pass values from this adapter to another activity:

```
....
     final Post post = mPosts.get(position);
.....

  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(post.getPublisher());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                final User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);



                holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PRESS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("postid", post.getPostid());
                        editor.apply();
                        ArrayList<String> arr;
                        arr= post.getIngrediantsList();
                        if (arr == null)
                        {
                            arr = new ArrayList<>();
                        }
                        final Intent i = new Intent(mContext, PostDetails.class);
                        i.putExtra("Instructions", post.getInstructions());
                        i.putExtra("title", post.getTitle());
                        i.putExtra("isVideo", post.getVideo());
                        i.putExtra("postimage", post.getPostimage());
                        i.putExtra("servings", post.getServings() + " servings");
                        i.putExtra("publisher", post.getPublisher());
                        i.putExtra("profileImg", user.getImageurl());
                        i.putExtra("MealType", post.getMeal());
                        i.putExtra("Cuisine", post.getCuisine());
                        i.putExtra("timePosted", pTime);
                        i.putExtra("Minutes", post.getMinutes() + "");
                        i.putExtra("Hours", post.getHours() + "");
                        i.putStringArrayListExtra("ingrediants", arr);
                        i.putExtra("username", user.getUsername());
                        i.putExtra("fullName", user.getFullName());
                        mContext.startActivity(i);
                        ((Activity) mContext).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

                    }
                });

            }
```

^
in this code, `post.getVideo()` and `arr` are null.

When I'm debugging my code, some data from firebase are shown as null:

[image]

Although they are there in the database, like this:

[image]

Here is a part of my model class:

```
public class Post {
    private String postid;
    private String postimage;
    private String title;
    private String publisher;
    private String Instructions;
    private String Vegetarian;
  //  private String Vegan;
    private String publishTime;
    private String Meal;
    private String Cuisine;
    private String Servings;
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private Boolean isVideo;


    private ArrayList<String> ingrediantsList;

    public ArrayList<String> getIngrediantsList() {
        return ingrediantsList;
    }

    public void setIngrediantsList(ArrayList<String> ingrediantsList) {
        this.ingrediantsList = ingrediantsList;
    }

    public String getCuisine() {
        return Cuisine;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
        Cuisine = cuisine;
    }

    public Post(String postid,Boolean isVideo, String postimage, String title, String publisher, String Instructions, String Vegetarian,String publishTime, String Meal, String Cuisine, String Servings, int hours, int minutes,ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        this.postid = postid;
        this.isVideo = isVideo;
        this.postimage = postimage;
        this.title = title;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.Instructions = Instructions;
        this.Vegetarian = Vegetarian;
      //  this.Vegan = Vegan;
        this.publishTime = publishTime;
        this.Meal = Meal;
        this.Cuisine = Cuisine;
        this.Servings= Servings;
        this.hours= hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.ingrediantsList = list;
    }

    public Post () { }
   // @Exclude
    public String getMeal() {
        return Meal;
    }
    public Boolean getVideo() {
        return isVideo;
    }

    public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
        isVideo = video;
    }
```

Edit:

Here is how I receive the `ingrediantslist` and `isVideo()` from the other activity:

```
     private void initIngrediantsList() {
    
            if (getIntent().hasExtra("ingrediants")) {
                ArrayList<String> list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("ingrediants");
                if (list.size() > 0) {
                    IngrediantsAdapter adatper = new IngrediantsAdapter(list, this);
                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adatper);
                    IngrediantsAdapter.setIngrediantListener(this);
                }
            }
        }
 isVideo = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isVideo", false);
        if (isVideo != null && isVideo) {
//          betterVideoPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: " + getIntent().getStringExtra("postimage"));
            try {
                player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
                playerView.setPlayer(player);
                playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //val mediaItem: MediaItem =    MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse("https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4"))

                MediaItem mediaItem =
                        MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("postimage")));

                player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);


                player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
                player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
                player.prepare();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: exception => " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `false` is of boolean type and may not have been serialized correctly and similar is the case with the `List` type. You should use `"false"` instead of `false` if you really want to receive the property `isVideo` of the `Post` object as `String`. Also please post the part where you get the data from Firebase, this is just a guess from my side

Comment: This is kind of right, I tried (snapshot.child("isVideo").getValue().toString().matches("true")), and it works unlike when I used post.getVideo(), but I need to use post.getVideo() because when I'm passing it to another activity it will do some things according to boolean value that was sent. Also, it works in other adapters but in this one, it is not working and it is weird

Comment: same with list it works in another adapter but in this adapter it returns null !

Comment: I guess it is a `Map` and not a `List` and as far as your `boolean` and `String` issue is concerned, I'd say, always use `String` to send data to your server, receive it as a `String` and then convert it to your return type as required.Inside your `getVideo` method, you can put your conversion logic. It's pretty safe that way

Comment: I added a snippet to my question so you can see how I get the data from the other activity, it might be easier for you to understand the issue. I will try your suggestion about the boolean value. thank you

Comment: Please add the code related to getting the data from firebase too, I think the real trouble is there

Comment: Do you mean in the adapter itself? I edited the first code snippet. you can see how I got values from firebase in the adapter

Comment: There is something incorrect in the code, your firebase database structure is of your `Post` class and you have tried to get a child called `"Users"` in the code above, please check again

Comment: yes I called child "Users" to have access to user.getUsername() and user.getFullName(). but I can user post from this line final Post post = mPosts.get(position); without accessing the "Posts" child. it it works this way only two data has null value which are the boolean and the list

Comment: I can use "post"***

Comment: I have no idea about this, what I can see is the `ingrediant` key in your database is a `List<Map>`